# It seems to be correct for / to me

Tags: grammar

While I answered a question, I wrote the following sentence to say that I agreed with the solution given by the OP.

> It seems to be correct *for* me.

Then, I wondered whether the following sentence would be better or not:

> It seems to be correct *to* me.

It seems that both are used on the Internet, but is one of them incorrect? or maybe with difference meanings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment

> It seems to be correct for me

implies that what you are referring to — in this case, the OP's solution — is correct *for you specifically* (for instance, because of the particular circumstances you find yourself in),

whereas

> It seems [to be] correct to me

means that you think it is *definitively* correct.

Comment: I honestly don't see the difference between the two. The usage of "xx me" in the first place means the user is not sure that it's correct.

Comment: @Raestloz - Often, when a person says that "X seems correct **to me**", they are appending "to me" not because they are unsure of their judgment, but because they want to soften what might otherwise sound excessively dogmatic.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer's already accepted, but I wanted to add something:

[This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=correct%20for%20me%2C%20correct%20to%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccorrect%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccorrect%20to%20me%3B%2Cc0) shows that both of the sentences are used about the same, with "to me" coming out slightly above the other. However, in [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be%20correct%20for%20me%2C%20be%20correct%20to%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbe%20correct%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0) "for me" comes out above, and after that both phrases get too specific to work in the calculator. Thus, whatever way you phrase it, it will still be correct for me *and* to me.

I agree with the definitions Erik Kowal put up.